# laravel config:cache throwing Call to undefined function parse_langs_to_array()

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

My laravel was working well untill i did a php artisan config:cache and am getting this.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]     Call to
>   undefined function parse_langs_to_array()

The site doesn't load up and it shows the "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." page without further information regardless of the fact that

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Comment: Try doing a `composer dump`

Comment: i get this generating optimized autoload files but still get the same error when when i do php artisan config:cache

Comment: Can you past the stacktrace from your log here?

Comment: funny thing, no error logs in apache

Comment: Not Apache! Laravel! `/storage/logs/laravel.log`